# Ruby 3.1 and workato connector SDK 1.3.4 upgrade gives failure of specs with wrong number of arguments

Tags: ruby, workato

We have upgraded the ruby version from 2.7 to ruby 3.1 and Workato to version 1.3.4 for my application. On this upgrade the specs are getting failed with a wrong number of arguments since passing the last argument as a keyword argument or hash parameter is deprecated

The approach I tried was using double splat operator (**), using braces to pass a hash, passing last argument as just key: value not as hash parameter.

Comment: Would you mind sharing your specs and the full error message?